# How to Execute Multiple post request simultaneously using angular js 1

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular1.6

I need to post same url with multiple parameters simultaneously .
how to achieve in angular 1

Comment: can you elaborate the description provide code if you have started with.

Comment: `post(url, data, [config])` You can pass all your parameters in data object https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it with `$http` service with `$http.post()` request. If you want to do multiple requests, you can do it a loop. E.g. `return $http.post(url,data).then((response)=>{return response.data;})`

This is where you need to clarify what do you mean by saying "*simultaneously*", because if you want to receive the response from all of these requests at the same time, then you need something more advanced like deferred objects. This is what `$q` service is for, it helps you to resolve such Promises.

Firstly you need to collect all of the asynchronous callbacks in an array:

```
var promises = [];
angular.forEach(array, function(element) { 
  promises.push( $http.post(url,element).then((res)=>{return res.data}) );
}
```

(Pass different parameters/data however you like)

Then you need to resolve all of them at the same time with `$q.all()`:

```
$q.all(promises).then((res)=>{ 
  /* do what you need with them, e.g:
     $q.defer().resolve(res)
  */
})
```

It should resolve an array with your data from previous requests in synch now.